# Cache Manager for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, caching

I would like to integrate a Cache Manager in an ASP.NET application. Basically I would like a page that would display what's in the cache and let me delete specific items or clear the whole cache. Ideally I would like as much information as possible, such as how long it's been in the cache for, the hit count, the size of the object, possibly see the object itself, etc. Of course I realize that some of this information might not be available from the default cache API.

I think it would be fairly easy to implement but I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I did a search and came across that one:
http://aspalliance.com/cachemanager/Screenshots.aspx

Just wondering if there are other options that I could compare.

Cheers

Comment: Good question, I ended up building my own one of these.

Comment: cxfx, you wanna post how you did it at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code to view the cache data.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/exploresessionandcache.aspx

Its not a cache manager, but its a good point to start.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following open source cache solution if you find it useful

http://csharp-source.net/open-source/cache-solutions

hope it helps